# web3.eth.pendingTransactions undefined error

Tags: web3js, pending-transactions

I am new in ethereum, I just run simple node.js program and using web3 api, and I send some ether from my account to another in my private ethereum network, after mining my transactions mined. I still have some pending transactions, my problem is that when I want to get the number of pending transactions by following code it has the error:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

, howeverو I can query the pending transactions numbers via geth javascript console by this query: `eth.pendingTransactions.length`

```
console.log(web3.eth.pendingTransactions.length);
```

Also, I used getPendingTransactions function with call back but still it has the same error.

I checked for some other functions and variables it works fine I do not know what is the problem with array of `pendingTransaction` and function `getPendingTransactions`.

Here is my simple code:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8000'));
console.log(web3.version.api);
var hashstring = web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: "X", to: "Y", value: web3.toWei(10, 'ether'),gas:30000});
console.log(hashstring);
console.log(web3.eth.pendingTransactions.length);
```

Comment: Maybe helpful if you post your actual failing code?

Comment: I just moved the code into the question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

`web3.eth.pendingTransactions` seems to be a Geth internal addition, I do not see it in the JSON-RPC or Web3 standard.

You are probably better off using this:

```
web3.eth.getBlock(
    "pending",
    function (error, block) {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } else {
            console.log(block.transactions.length); 
        }
    });
```